# Zend throws "Session already started" exception, when I have not started a session, what gives?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'session has already been started by session.auto-start or session_start()' in /usr/include/ZendFramework-1.11.3/library/Zend/Session.php on line 462
```

It happens every reload.  Things I have done:

- Ensured that session.autostart=0 in my php.ini
- searched my entire application for calls to session_start(), there are none
- placed the following session configuration information in my config.ini:

  ```
  resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
  resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
  resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
  ```
- removed the above from my config.ini, didn't make a difference
- restarted apache, several times
- finally I only use Zend_Session_Namespace(), which is initialized in my controller's `init()` function.

I'm getting that error every time.  What gives?  What else haven't I checked?  The only place the word "session" even exists in my Application (outside of the Zend library) is in this one controller:

```
<?php

class ContributeController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    private $_session;

    private function getSession() {
        return $this->_session;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->_session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('contribute');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    }

    public function addAction() {
        $this->getSession()->form = new Application_Form_Contribute_Add_Main();
        $this->view->form = $this->getSession()->form;
    }

    public function importAction() {}


}

?>
```

Here's a grep search of my php.ini for `^session`:

```
session.save_handler = files
session.use_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly = 
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_divisor     = 100
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.bug_compat_42 = 1
session.bug_compat_warn = 1
session.referer_check =
session.entropy_length = 0
session.entropy_file =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 4
```

`session.auto_start`, clearly off.

Why am I getting this error every time?  What is going on here?

**Edit** For the moment it seems this was caused by attempting to store too much in the session when I attempted to store that form.  When I rewrote my code to store a very simple array outlining the form's structure instead, the error went away and hasn't returned.  I may return to this if it reappears and I'm not confident that it won't yet.

Comment: Can you explain "It happens every reload" please?

Comment: @Adrian World - I think he means 'on every request', or every time he hits a page.

Comment: @Adrian World karim79 is correct.

Comment: As you've already grep'ed your php.ini for `session.auto-start` (hint: check `phpinfo()` as well as the source-code it's a `PHP_INI_ALL` setting), you can additionally grep the sources for `session_start` as well.

Comment: Hmm, what about whitespaces or bom signature before `<?php` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Check that the session data folder defined in your application.ini exists and is writable : when it is not the case, the same exception is thrown with this bogus message.

Comment: I had this exact problem. There was a typo in the session path name in my config file. It really is not a helpful error message in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that you may have overlooked, would be this call somewhere in your application (bootstrap, perhaps?):

```
Zend_Session::start();
```

Comment: I tried that. Calling it in the bootstrap fails.  Calling it before `$application` worked some of the time, but it the error will still pop up on some refreshes.  Even so, that feels like a hack and a bandaid and doesn't explain the greater cause.  A theory I'm testing at the moment is that my form is too big for session and causing it to choke on serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, how about dump a debug_trace() into a file within the Zend_Session_Namespace constructor and see what you get per request. This should at least show you that the cause is outside of Zend or that indeed there are two close calls and especially where they are coming from.

I somehow think you are reloading your form page internally causing the init() controller to run twice. Starting the session earlier like karim79 suggested in the bootstrap should cure such cases.

Comment: Why would new calling new on Zend_Session_Namespace() twice generate this error, though?  Should I not be able to call that to get multiple namespaces?  And should it not detect it when I call it on the same namespace and handle that gracefully?

Comment: In theory yes but there are certain conditions when the Zend_Session is reset. But I see in your update above this is probably not the case with your problem, though.

Comment: While Adrian World doesn't mention any conditions when this is true, I found that GC will collect Zend_Session when it's only referenced by Zend_Session_Namespace objects that get slated for collection.  When I added a Zend_Session::start() call in my bootstrap, it fixed my issue.